# Ckeditor pasar por ajax

Tags: php, ajax, ckeditor

Hola buenas que tal necesito de su ayuda a como pasar los parámetros del ckeditor por ajax. Lo tengo en venta modal.

Tengo el formulario asi el ajax esta en .js que hace la operación de guardar los datos:

```
<textarea name="editorVenta" id="editorVenta" class="ckeditor" cols="45" rows="8"></textarea>
```

```
        $( "#add_noticia" ).submit(function( event ) {
         var parametros = $(this).serialize();
         var data = new FormData(this);

            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax/guardar_noticia.php",
                    data: parametros,
                    cache: false,
                    data: data,
                    processData: false, 
                    contentType: false, 
                    success: function (resultado) {          
                    },
                    beforeSend: function(objeto){
                        $("#resultados").html("Enviando...");
                      },
                    success: function(datos){
                    $("#resultados").html(datos);
                    load(1);
                    $('#addNoticiaModal').modal('hide');
                  }
            });
          event.preventDefault();
        });
```

Podrían ayudarme por favor.

Comment: Y por qué en vez de coger todo el form, no coges los valores de cada campo, `data.append('contenidoCK' : $('#editorVenta').val());` y así con cada campo

Answer (score 0):

La documentación de `CKEditor` debe mencionar un método del *API* para obtener el texto que editaste usándolo. Te recomiendo buscar en la documentación del plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione asi espero le ayude a otra persona.
En el formulario modal

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 CKEDITOR.replace ("editorVenta");
</script>
```

En el ajax

```
        $( "#add_noticia" ).submit(function( event ) {
         var parametros = $(this).serialize();
        var editorVenta= CKEDITOR.instances.editorVenta.updateElement();
        var dataString ='editorVenta='+editorVenta;      
        var data = new FormData(this);
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax/guardar_noticia.php",
                    data: parametros,
                    cache: false,
                    data : dataString,
                    data : data,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false, 
                    success: function (resultado) {          
                    },
                    beforeSend: function(objeto){
                        $("#resultados").html("Enviando...");
                      },
                    success: function(datos){
                    $("#resultados").html(datos);
                    load(1);
                    $('#addNoticiaModal').modal('hide');
                  }
            });
          event.preventDefault();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

21 de enero de 2022 funciona pero lo actualizo un poco por si alguien lo nesecita

```
var allEditors = document.querySelectorAll('.ckeditor');
    let myeditor;
    for (var i = 0; i < allEditors.length; ++i) {
        ClassicEditor
        .create(allEditors[i])
        .then( newEditor => {
            myeditor = newEditor;
        })
        .catch( error => {
            console.error( error );
        });
        
    };
    $( "#send-fmr" ).submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var parametros = $(this).serialize();
        var editorVenta= myeditor.getData();      
        var dataString ='editorVenta1='+editorVenta;      
        var data = new FormData(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "save.php",
                data: parametros,
                cache: false,
                data : dataString,
                data : data,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false, 
                success: function (res) {
                    if (res === '1') {
                        alert('hecho');
                    }          
                }
            });
    });
```

lo que hice fue crear un for para que a cada textarea con la clase ckeditor se le apliquen ckeditor5 y con la ayuda del codigo de Herless modificando solo un atributo logre mandar por ajax mis datos cabe aclarar que yo lo usare en un form con varios textarea por lo que o bie tienes que crear atro for para encontar los textarea que tienen ckeditor aplicado y obtener su valor por medio de getData()