# ckeditor5 no envia el texto del textarea por javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ckeditor

bien lo que estoy tratando de hacer es enviar un form extenso (en este ejemplo solo el textarea) por medio de ajax usando el plugin de ckeditor para enviar texto enriquecido, la cosa es que el form me lo toma y lo envia sin problema el asunto es que el valor del textarea lo ignora y lo envia vacio. Como puedo mandar todo el form completo por ajax para que me tome el valor de los textarea, investiganndo me encontre que se puede acceder al valor de el text area desde una funcion propia del plugin pero solo eso he podido logar no he podido enviar el valor. aclaro que si lo hago por php si manda el valor

anexo codigo

```
<body>
<style>
    .ck-editor__editable {
        min-height: 150px;
        max-height: 150px;
    }
</style>
<form id="send-fmr">
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 5rem;">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3><b>Ingrese Su Mensaje:</b></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <textarea class="ckeditor form-control" name="texto" id="editor"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" id="send">Enviar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<br>
<?php
include("conexion.php");
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM `imagen`");

while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){
    ?>
    <div class="container" style="margin-bottom: 5rem;">
        <form action="update.php" method="POST">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3><b>Mensaje:</b></h3>
                    <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $res['id']?>" hidden>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="update" id="editor"><?php echo $res['image']?></textarea>
                    <textarea class="form-control" style="height: 150px;"><?php echo htmlentities($res['image']) ?></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <a href="gen_word.php?i=<?php echo $res['id']?>" class="btn btn-outline-success" id="generar">Generar Word</a>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark" name="actu">Actualizar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    
    <?php
}

?>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>    
    var allEditors = document.querySelectorAll('#editor');
    var myeditor;
    for (var i = 0; i < allEditors.length; ++i) {
        ClassicEditor.create((allEditors[i]))
                     .then(editor => {myeditor = editor;})
    };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#send').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var texto = myeditor.getData();
        const data = $('#send-fmr').serialize();
        console.log(data);
        //var contenido = CKEDITOR.instances['#editor'].getData();
        //const formData = new FormData($("#send-fmr")[0]);
        //console.log(formData);
        /*$.ajax({
            url: 'save.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(res){
                if (res === "1") {
                    alert('Se guardo awebooo!!!!');
                }else {
                    alert('alv se dio un madrazo');
                }
            }
        });*/
    })
</script>
```

Comment: El atributo [ID debe ser único](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id), pero lo estás repitiendo en el ciclo para cada campo de texto, siempre tomará solo el valor del primer elemento encontrado.

Comment: eso lo se pero ya sea que lo tome por id o por clase me da ese mismo problema ademas en un formulario real nesecitare varios de ellos

Answer (score 0):

Para quien lo Nesecite :

```
<textarea class="ckeditor form-control" name="editorVenta1" id="editorVenta"></textarea>

var allEditors = document.querySelectorAll('.ckeditor');
    let myeditor;
    for (var i = 0; i < allEditors.length; ++i) {
        ClassicEditor
        .create(allEditors[i])
        .then( newEditor => {
            myeditor = newEditor;
        })
        .catch( error => {
            console.error( error );
        });
        
    };
    $( "#send-fmr" ).submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var parametros = $(this).serialize();
        var editorVenta= myeditor.getData();      
        var dataString ='editorVenta1='+editorVenta;      
        var data = new FormData(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "save.php",
                data: parametros,
                cache: false,
                data : dataString,
                data : data,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false, 
                success: function (res) {
                    if (res === '1') {
                        alert('hecho');
                    }          
                }
            });
    });
```

lo que hice fue crear un for para que a cada textarea con la clase ckeditor se le apliquen ckeditor5 y con la ayuda del codigo de [Herless](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/336498/ckeditor-pasar-por-ajax/510364#510364) modificando solo un atributo logre mandar por ajax mis datos cabe aclarar que yo lo usare en un form con varios textarea por lo que o bie tienes que crear atro for para encontar los textarea que tienen ckeditor aplicado y obtener su valor por medio de getData()